# Only z component of angular momentum $\vec{L} = I\vec{\omega}$ considered?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

The derivation of the angular momentum of a rigid body in terms of the moment of inertia considers only the z component. Why are not the other components considered ?
[image: Derivation of angular momentum of Rigid Body]

Comment: This is from Kleppner - pg. 253

Comment: Don't use `$$ $$` in title.

Comment: Isn't the rotation about the _z_-axis? So the distance along the rotation axis aren't important.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancelling internal forces/moments term when deriving inertial matrix](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173086/)

Comment: I think the author is afraid to use cross products which is what you need when considering all the 3D components.

Comment: He begins by saying "consider the body rotating around $Z$ axis. Simple.

Comment: The thing is: this is not a limitation of any kind. You have a rotating body, thus you have one special axis. You can alway call the axis z.

Comment: @ja72 The relationship between this question and your proposed duplicate is not obvious to me.

Comment: @rob In the proposed duplicate the MMOI and angular momentum are formed for a point considering the summation of small masses. The question here ultimately is how different is angular momentum when considering all components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $z$ axis is of course not special. However, the angular momentum is a vector quantity, and it is often easiest to compute a vector quantity by calculating each component separately. On the other hand, precisely because the $z$ axis is not special, the same calculation will apply to the $x$ and $y$ components, as long as you change what needs to be changed. This last part means that a rigid body really has *three* moments of inertia -- one for each axis. The formal way to do it is with an object called the [inertia tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#The_inertia_tensor). <sup>1</sup>

You can choose the $z$-axis to be the axis of rotation, and then the $x$ and $y$ components will be zero, so that you only need the $z$ component. This amounts to demanding that $L = L_z\hat z$ where $\hat z$ is a unit vector, but then if $\tau$ is the torque $$\tau = \frac{d}{dt} L = \frac{d}{dt} L_z \hat{z}$$
so $\frac{d}{dt} \hat z$ has to be non-zero in general. Thus the cost is that you have to find how $\hat z$ changes with time. That [can be done however](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics)), 
and any mechanics textbook should treat it.

---

1. The inertia tensor has six independent components because it's symmetric, but three only encode the transformation between the chosen coordinate system and the [principal axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Principal_axes). It's really only the principal moments that are properties of the rigid body itself. Three principal moments + three Euler angles = six components.